# Где почитать про международные стандарты составления документации на с#

Tags: c#, документация

Скажите, где есть база знаний, описаны международные стандарты и правила написания, можно посмотреть в хорошие  примеры документации реальных проектов  для языка с# на английском, так как все проекты практически на английском. Остальные языки - в меншинстве.

Comment: Подобного рода вопросы не очень подходят под правила stackoverflow, попробуйте лучше задать вопрос в чате по c# или в общем чате.

Comment: как найти такой чат?

Comment: А где тут чат? 8)

Comment: @A K [Подобного рода вопросы не очень подходят под правила stackoverflow] Вопрос напрямую относится к программированию, ибо выпуск документации на ПО это неотъемлемая часть создания ПО.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 К программированию - относятся. Но "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ"

Comment: @NewView https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @A K [ "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ"] Посмотрите ниже, я дал объективно верный ответ без всякого переформулирования вопроса. :-)

Comment: Как найти чаты: в правом верхнем углу кнопка: Список всех сайтов. Жмем ее, там будет ссылка "чат".

Comment: Документация может быть для внутренного использования (описание кода) и для внешнего (описание API). Для последнего смотрите swagger - ныне это стандарт де-факто. К тому же в .NET-проектах WebAPI он подключается парой строк и документация генерируется автоматически.

Comment: Я попробовала писать на английском и думала оно придёт на английскую версию сайта

Answer (score 2):

Есть знаменитый ГОСТ 19.*** на оформление программной документации.

Вот ссылки (естественно это не все ссылки, там еще много ссылок можно нагуглить):

http://guap.ru/guap/standart/kach/espd_19.001-19.781.pdf
http://www.swrit.ru/gost-espd.html

Основной документ как всегда спецификация. Еще часто выпускают описание применения. Реже выпускают описание программы. Но это все конечно зависит от сложности программы и прочих факторов. От языка стандарт не зависит, вернее стандарт распространяется на все языки от ассемблера до лиспа.

UPD1:

Все это называется "Единая система программной документации".

UPD2:

> Для языка с# на английском, так как все проекты практически на
>   английском.

Где взять английский стандарт я не знаю, но думаю, что русский стандарт на документацию к ПО цельнотянут с английского стандарта. Погуглите, думаю что сразу найдете. Или еще проще поискать на сайте ANSI или МЭК.

UPD3:

> Для языка с# на английском, так как все проекты практически на
>   английском.

И да, если Вас интересует англоязычные документы, то логичнее было бы спрашивать на англоязычном сайте stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: Для C# удобно использовать специальные комментарии в коде, которые например VS умеет преобразовывать в xml, а из xml можно уже генеральных что удобно, как правило это markdown, вот пример такого [конвертора](https://github.com/PetersSharp/stCoCServer/blob/master/stCoCServer/stTools/XmlDocUtil/XmlDocUtil.cs)

Comment: Так-же, де-факто стандартом стал `doxygen`, большинство IDE поддерживает его синтаксис как с помощью плагинов, так и из 'коробки'. Вводная статейка на русском https://habr.com/post/252101/